# Is `eval` the only way to create functions with dynamically determined arity in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, eval, arity

I'm using a JavaScript spy library,
[simple-spy](https://github.com/tjoskar/simple-spy).

I've found out that when spying on a given function,
the resulting spy always has an arity of 0.

This creates a problem with my use of
[this currying function](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry).

So I've [submitted a pull-request
that adds arity transparency to
the spy library](https://github.com/tjoskar/simple-spy/pull/3).

The code looks like this:

```
function spy(fn) {
    const inner = (...args) => {
        stub.callCount++;
        stub.args.push(args);
        return fn(...args);
    };

    // ends up a string like
    // 'a,b,c,d'
    // depending on the `fn.length`
    const stubArgs = Array(fn.length)
        .fill(null)
        .map((m, i) => String.fromCodePoint(97 + i))
        .join();

    const stubBody = 'return inner(...arguments);';

    // this seems to be the only way
    // to create a function with
    // programmatically specified arity
    const stub = eval(
        // the wrapping parens is to
        // prevent it from evaluating as
        // a function declaration
        `(function (${stubArgs}) { ${stubBody} })`
    );

    stub.reset = () => {
        stub.callCount = 0;
        stub.args = [];
    };

    stub.reset();

    return stub;
}

exports.spy = spy;
```

This seems to work.

Is it possible to do this
without the use of `eval`?

Is it possible to
reduce the use of `eval`
to even less that this?

I'm aware that there are other issues
with this spy implementation.
It is simplistic and it works
for my use case so far.

Comment: You can use `Function` and set the arguments. Not much much better but better. You can also set `.length` with defineProperty on functions

Answer (score 2):

Like [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) wrote, I used a simple:

```
function spy(fn) {
    const stub = (...args) => {
        stub.callCount++;
        stub.args.push(args);
        return fn(...args);
    };

    stub.reset = () => {
        stub.callCount = 0;
        stub.args = [];
    };

    stub.reset();

    Object.defineProperty(stub, 'length', {value: fn.length});

    return stub;
}

exports.spy = spy;
```

Much, much better looking.